# How to wire light and fan on a cathedral ceiling?

Tags: ceiling-fan, light

I want to add some lights to the roof joist and a ceiling fan to the ridge beam.  The height of the ridge beam is 20 feet.  I plan to run romex up the wall to the peak.  At the peak should I continue with romex and staple to the beam or transition to a conduit/ wire mold to run along the beam.  The wire is not susceptible to damage due to the height.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Romex is a bit easier overall, so just use it the whole way. The catch is that if you transition to conduit then you need to have the box with the transition always accessible. You can cover up Romex with wiremold or something else, though if it is the standard 14 AWG white then you'll hardly notice it against the corner of the white beams 20' up.